# How to repeat each dimension of a 3-D matrix in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Say I have a 3-D matrix `a` of dimension [X,Y,Z],

```
a(:,:,1) = [1 2; 3 4];
a(:,:,2) = [5 6; 7 8];
```

Is there a way to repeat each entry of `a`, say N times and construct a new matrix, `b`, of dimension [X, Y, N*Z]? For example, if N=2, to have a matrix `b` like so,

```
%repeat first element of 'a' 2ce
b(:,:,1) = [1 2; 3 4];
b(:,:,2) = [1 2; 3 4];

%repeat second element of 'a' 2ce
b(:,:,3) = [5 6; 7 8];
b(:,:,4) = [5 6; 7 8];
```

Using a nested loop can achieve this of course, for e.g.

```
%not tested, but should work
b = zeros(X,Y,N*Z);

k=1;

for j=1:Z
  for i=1:N
     b(:,:,k) = a(:,:,j);
     k=k+1;
  end
end
```

But I'll like to know if there's an inbuilt function available for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an index of the form 1,1,2,2,... (example for `N=2`) and use it in the third dimension:

```
b = a(:,:,ceil(1/N:1/N:size(a,3)));
```